# entity framework System.NotSupportedException on mono

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mono

I Have 3 very simple model.

```
public abstract class User : IEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Password as SHA256
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SocialAccount> SocialLogins { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher : User
{
    public string Qwert { get; set; }
}
```

executing code

```
                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<RelationalDatabase>());

                var rel = new RelationalDatabase();

                rel.Users.Add(
                    new Teacher
                        {
                            FirstName = "Hayri",
                            LastName = "Tüfekçilerli",
                            UserName = "hayri",
                            Password = "asdnfaksjnfkasjfn"
                        });
                rel.SaveChanges();
```

Error:

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! --->
>   System.NotSupportedException: The type 'GoAndTeach.Models.Student' and
>   the type 'GoAndTeach.Models.Student' both have the same simple name of
>   'Student' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a
>   given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or
>   call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a
>   property or type from the model.   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.GetExistingEdmType[EntityType]
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel model, System.Type
>   type) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapDerivedTypes
>   (System.Type type, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType
>   entityType) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder+<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_7 (System.Type
>   type) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator33`1[System.Type].MoveNext ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[Type]
>   (IEnumerable`1 ts, System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel model) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderManifest providerManifest,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection providerConnection) [0x00000] in :0
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2[System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext,System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel].GetValue
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext input) [0x00000] in
>   :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook (Nancy.NancyContext context,
>   Nancy.ErrorPipeline pipeline, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in :0

Same assembly, same code works on .Net Framework 4.5. On mono, Im getting that weird error.

Entity framework Version: 6.1
MysqlConnector Version: 6.8.3.2

How can i fix this?

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2147

Comment: @Pawel Yep, exactly same. I have also encountered different problems with different frameworks. So, I have understood that mono is not production ready yet :)

Comment: This is working on Windows(.Net) **MySql** or only MSSQL? Because sounds more like provider problem to me.

Comment: @DavidKarlaš this is working on  .Net Framework+MySql, no MSSQL.

Comment: I can also confirm that the code works on Windows + MySql, but not on Linux (Mono) + MySql.